# Passing data with typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem when passing data from html like this

```
Karbohidrat :{{karbohidrat}} <button ion-button (click)="cekHalamanMakanan('karbohidrat')">Lihat makanan karbohidrat</button> <br>
```

and receive the karbohidrat using cekHalamanMakanan function like this

```
cekHalamanMakanan(value)
  {
   }
```

When i try to console.log, it gives me the correct answer
and then i want to push value to an array like this and sent the array to next page using navctrl

```
gizi : any;    
this.gizi= {};
        this.gizi = this.navParams.data;
        this.karbohidrat=this.gizi.karbohidrat;
        this.protein_hewani=this.gizi.protein_hewani;
        this.protein_nabati=this.gizi.protein_nabati;
        this.lemak=this.gizi.lemak;
        this.jenis=this.gizi.value;
```

and receive it using navparams

```
this.makanan = {}
    this.makanan = this.navParams.data;
    this.variabel = this.makanan.jenis;
```

but when i try to see it using console.log it gives me "undefined"..

heres the full code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { HalamanmakananPage} from '../halamanmakanan/halamanmakanan'

/**
 * Generated class for the RekomendasiPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-rekomendasi',
  templateUrl: 'rekomendasi.html',
})
export class RekomendasiPage {
  gizi : any;
  karbohidrat : number;
  protein_hewani : number;
  protein_nabati : number;
  lemak : number;
  jenis : string;
  value : string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RekomendasiPage');
  }

  cekHalamanMakanan(value)
  {
    console.log(value);

    this.gizi= {};
    this.gizi = this.navParams.data;
    this.karbohidrat=this.gizi.karbohidrat;
    this.protein_hewani=this.gizi.protein_hewani;
    this.protein_nabati=this.gizi.protein_nabati;
    this.lemak=this.gizi.lemak;
    this.jenis=this.gizi.value;
    console.log(this.karbohidrat,this.protein_hewani,this.protein_nabati,this.lemak,this.jenis);

    this.navCtrl.push(HalamanmakananPage,this.gizi);
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(value);` in that code? And what it in `this.navParams.data;`?

Comment: in console.log(value) i got karbohidrat that means correct.but in the this.navParams.data i got undefined

Answer (score 0):

In this function it looks like you never end up using the value passed in ('karbohidrat') other than log it to the console. Everything else you're doing just uses what was passed in to NavParams when the page loaded.

```
cekHalamanMakanan(value)
  {
    console.log(value);

    this.gizi= {};
    this.gizi = this.navParams.data;
    this.karbohidrat=this.gizi.karbohidrat;
    this.protein_hewani=this.gizi.protein_hewani;
    this.protein_nabati=this.gizi.protein_nabati;
    this.lemak=this.gizi.lemak;
    this.jenis=this.gizi.value;
    console.log(this.karbohidrat,this.protein_hewani,this.protein_nabati,this.lemak,this.jenis);

    this.navCtrl.push(HalamanmakananPage,this.gizi);
  }
```

Comment: so what should i do ? i want to pass karbohidrat from value to next page like that code..

Comment: if you do this.navCtrl.push(HalamanmakananPage, value), that value will end up in the nav params of the next page. Do you want to pass the string value as it is, or do some business logic first?

Comment: oh i see and then how to send it ? i want to send this.gizi too to the next page, and how i accept this.gizi and value for the next page ?

Comment: Probably compose them into an object and send that object through the NavParams. this.navCtrl.push(HalamanmakananPage, {value: value, gizie: this.gizi}

Comment: and how about in navparams? i use this.params.data twice or not ?

Comment: The 2nd argument in navCtrl.push() is navParams

Comment: so in the next lage i just write  this.something = this.navparams.data  that mean it contain both of this.gizi and the value ?

Comment: Yes I think so. I don’t know how your data is structured I can’t help you out any more than that.